# Send multiple input using FormData

Tags: javascript, html, form-data

I have this form:

```
<form action="#" id="form-add">
    <input type="text" name="test[]" value="hello">
    <input type="text" name="test[]" value="bye">
    <button type="submit"><Submit/button>
</form>
```

And I want, when the user submits, this information to be sent via AJAX using FormData like this:

```
$('form-add').submit(function (event)
    {
        //Prevents from submitting form
        event.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData();

        var form_fields = $('#form-add').serializeArray();

        $.each(form_fields, function (key, input)
        {
            formData.append(input.name, input.value);
        });

    });
```

The problem is when I try to check the entries inside the variable formData, it only shows the value of the first input:

```
console.log(formData.get('teste[]'));

//Returns
hello
```

How can I send this kind of inputs using FormData?

Answer (score 0):

It will send all values. But if you want to check on a client you'll need to use [`getAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll) method.

```js
const form = new FormData

form.append('a', 1)
form.append('a', 2)

console.log(form.getAll('a'))
```